# jQuery dataTable not working (checked other questions, didn't help)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with PHP and I made a table which gets results from some simple search page I made, all is working fine but I'd like to make the table that displays my data a jQuery dataTable. I went ahead and did everything required (I think) and it's still not working, I'm really lost now.

Here's what I have in my  tag that's related to the dataTable part

```
 <!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- the links for the data tables -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tablee').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

and my table has this in it `<table class="table table-striped"  id="tablee">`

I also have this at the bottom of the page, for bootstrap

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Tried removing it but it didn't help.

Also from what I know, putting the scripts at the bottom of the page is better practice for increased page load speed, yes? I'm just trying to get it to work for now. Thanks!

Adding full HTML code of the table as requested.

```
  <div class="row">

        <table class="table table-striped"  id="tablee">
           <thead> 

                        <tr>
                    <th>field</th>
                    <th>field</th>
                    <th>field</th>
                    <th>field</th>
                    <th>field</th>
                    <th>field</th>
                    <th>field</th>

                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                     <?php echo '<td class="col-md-1"> ' ?> <?php echo "<a href='view.php?id=".$row['id'] ."'>" . $row['field'] .  "</a>"; ?> </td>
                     <td class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $row['field']; ?> </td> 
                      <td class="col-md-1"> <?php echo $row['field']; ?> </td>
                      <td class="col-md-1"> <?php echo $row['field']; ?> </td>
                      <td class="col-md-1"> <?php echo $row['field']; ?> </td>
                      <td class="col-md-1"> <?php echo $row['field']; ?> </td>
                      <td class="col-md-1"> <?php echo $row['field'];?> </td> 
                      </tr>}//end while ?>
       <!-- instead of table style make divs --> 
       </tbody>
       </table>
       </div> <!-- /table row -->
```

My header scripts

Loading the CSS as you suggested the other day, then loading these scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jquery for the data tables -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script> $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tablee').DataTable();
}); </script>
```

Comment: You want client side datatable ?

Comment: eh I guess yes. I want to give the users the ability to search and sort and have pagination for big results.

Comment: Your html, css and js code looks good. There might be an issue in how you have included: **jquery.dataTables.min.css** and  **query.dataTables.min.js**

Comment: Add http: or https: before **//cdn.datatables.net/**

Comment: @Bimal `//` will default to either http or https in all modern browsers.

Comment: Is this just a typo? You have `('#tablee')` did you mean `#table` ?

Comment: @Soviut yes, thats true but I was talking from debugging perspective. So I suggested the change in url.

Comment: @Bimal then it would be better to ask if they were seeing any errors in their browser console, rather than suggesting arbitrary code changes in comments.

Comment: @Soviut yup, my mistake. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the order in which you are including javascript files. For example put the follwing javascript files in order:

1. jQuery file
2. Bootstrap file (optional)
3. Datatable file
4. Your Javascript file

Also use the appropriate jQuery version file for the used DataTable file. For this you can check the Datatables documentation.

I am giving here a link to an example: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Scroll down below and check the tabs (Javascript, Html and Css) to get a good idea about what you need.

Comment: The problem was that I was referencing another Jquery file at the bottom of the page, while the datatables jquery was still at the header. So the newest jquery loaded, then the datatables jquery then an older version of jquery that came with bootstrap(bottom of the page). So I guess when the bottom of the page one got loaded it became as if the datatables jquery was loaded before the actual jquery needed for it to work. Thanks for your concern man, this answer made me look at it again, now it's solved.

Comment: @Mar1AK Its great that you found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];
    data.push(
        [1,"Sasha","Brenna","0800 1111"],
        [2,"Sage","Mia","(01012) 405872"],
    );

    $('#data_table').DataTable( {
        data:           data,
        deferRender:    true,
        scrollY:        200,    // Y scroll fix to 200px
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scroller:       true
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<table id="data_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Emp Code</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <!-- Dynamic Body -->
        </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7z6gzn7/)

Comment: I placed your function in a script in the <head> tag and changed my table's ID to data_table. It didn't work, weird.

Comment: @Mar1AK Just a check. Are you using multiple jquery versions in your project ?

Comment: @Mar1AK Please share the complete html code so that it would be easy to solve the issue.

Comment: @Mar1AK You are missing a </tbody> in your html code. And can you tell me where are you placing css and js links for jQuery plus DataTables in your php file.

Comment: @Bimal Thanks, corrected the </tbody> tag and i'm placing all the links in the <header> element they are not in the PHP code.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I tried and still trying your code, same thing. Nothing happens. It's like the jQuery isn't loading at all on the page or something...

Comment: @Mar1AK Are you using any other javascript library other than jQuery ?

Comment: @Bimal I mentioned in the question that i'm importing the javascript and jquery from bootstrap, tried removing those it didn't help. Problem is that I literally copy and pasted the links from a working page from another project and still didn't work on this one...

Comment: In my jsfiddle I am using `jquery`, `datatable jquery`, `datatable css` only

Comment: @Mar1AK Ideally your code should work. I see no bugs in your code. Lets try doing things from another angle is the id #tablee unique.

Comment: @Mar1AK I mean no other element in html uses the id **tablee**, right ?

Comment: @Bimal Yes it is unique. I have no other tables on the page. Only a HTML form and a button to search using POST method. There are no other ID tags in the page actually, just on this table.

Comment: @Mar1AK can you make a jsFiddle of your code ? It will help us to solve the issue.

Comment: **Try these links:** https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-datatable-client-side-demo-implementation/blob/master/index.html and for **demo:** https://pandeyz.github.io/Jquery-datatable-client-side-demo-implementation/

Comment: @Bimal Would you like to join a meeting where I share my screen? 
https://join.me/maralkhaleel
It's live now.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the HTML for your table, so it's impossible to know if your selector is correct. However, you may just have a typo.

You have:

```
$('#tablee')
```

Did you mean to put:

```
$('#table')
```

Comment: Not a typo error as html looks like this:  **<table class="table table-striped"  id="tablee">**

Comment: @Bimal how do you know? It isn't in the original question.

Comment: tablee is intended. The table's ID is tablee and so it is like that in the jQuery function. It's just a variable's name

Comment: @Soviut Please check the question once again. It mentions: **and my table has this in it <table class="table table-striped"  id="tablee">**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was referencing another Jquery file at the bottom of the page, while the datatables jquery was still at the header. So the newest jquery loaded, then the datatables jquery then an older version of jquery that came with bootstrap(bottom of the page). So I guess when the bottom of the page one got loaded it became as if the datatables jquery was loaded before the actual jquery needed for it to work. It is now fixed

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- jquery for the data tables -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script> $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tablee').DataTable();
}); </script>
```